# Greater than/Less than issue

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate user-input. If the number user has entered is greater than 3, then it should throw error 'Too high', if it is lesser than 0.15, then 'Too low'. If it's between 3 and 0.15, then it should show 'Okay'.

The problem with my code is that if the user has entered a negative value, it still shows 'Okay' to him. It seems regardless of what the user enters, it shows 'Okay'.

This is the code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        vel = $('#vel').val();
        validVel(vel);
});

function validVel(v) {

    if (v > 3) {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Too High";
        $('.er').text(error);   
    }
    else if (v < 0.15) {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Too Low";
        $('.er').text(error);   
    }
    else {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Okay";
        $('.er').text(error);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think `.val()` doesn't necessarily return a numeric value.

Comment: what browser and versions of jquery are you using. it works fine.  here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBvZh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `parseFloat` in your function to ensure the equality checks are valid. As pointed out by WilQu you should also include an [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#isNaN_Function) test -

```
function validVel(v) {

    fv = parseFloat(v);

    if (fv > 3) {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Too High";
        $('.er').text(error);   
    }
    else if (fv < 0.15) {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Too Low";
        $('.er').text(error);   
    }
    else if (isNaN(fv)) {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Not a number";
        $('.er').text(error);   
    }   
    else {
        $('.er').fadeIn(2000);
        var error = "Okay";
        $('.er').text(error);
    }
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/AyhRS/7

Comment: +1 to WilQu as well for reminding us that `NaN` will be considered "okay" in the above function, since it's neither >3 nor <0.15.

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` is returning a string. In order to convert it to a number, simply put a plus sign before `$('#vel').val()`, i.e. `vel = +$('#vel').val();`

Comment: And as @WilQu pointed out below, you'll need to check that the number conversion actually worked (if the user puts the word 'Cows!' in the box, it ain't gonna convert to a number).

Answer (score 2):

The value you're trying to validate is a string. Use the `parseFloat` function. Don't forget to check that you don't get `NaN`.

Comment: To be specific: fuz3d should check `if (isNaN(fv)) {...} ` before checking if `fv > 3`. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AyhRS/6/